# Solution verification: $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x^3-4)^{\frac13}}$ series expansion at positive and negative $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, solution-verification, binomial-theorem

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x^3-4)^{\frac13}}$$

Find $a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2$ such that :

\begin{align}
& f(x)=a_1x+b_1+\frac {c_1}x+\frac{d_1}{x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right) , &
 x\to \infty\\
& f(x)=a_2x+b_2+\frac {c_2}x+\frac{d_2}{x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right) , &
 x\to -\infty
\end{align}

My attempt:

\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(x^3-4)^{\frac13}}
& = \frac{x^2}{x\left(1-\frac4{x^3}\right)^{\frac13}} \\
& = x\left(1-\frac4{x^3}\right)^{-\frac13} \\
& = x\left(1+\frac{4}{3x^3}+\frac{32}{9x^6}+o\left(\frac1{x^6}\right)\right) \\
& = x+\frac4{3x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)
\end{align}

$a_1=a_2=1,b_1=b_2=0,c_1=c_2=0,d_1=d_2=\frac43$.
Correct ?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Bernard   -1/3 over 2 is 2/9

Comment: @Bernard No its $-\frac13(-\frac13-1)$ over 2

Comment: It seems I messed up computing the coefficients…